# Migrate local git-svn repo to a new svn branch

Tags: git, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, git-svn

My place of work uses svn and I have been using git-svn for the past few months to work in a git environment and interface with the svn repo as a remote.

The svn repo looks like this (Nnnn is the version number)

//path/../ApplicationName/Nnnn/all_the_code

When we start a new release it branches to a new version number.  Our svn gui (tortoise SVN) knows how to branch somehow (I never looked into the internals)

I synced the remote svn repo up to the version number.  When svn branches, how can I tell git to pull whenever I 'git svn update' from the new branch?  Has anyone done this before?

Thanks, and sorry for any ignorance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it here

http://theadmin.org/articles/git-svn-switch-to-a-different-a-svn-url/

Looks like this process could be packaged into a git svn switch command.